# Redux: Waiting for state changes before doing something else

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

In a hypothetical app, a user can create a book and by default that book has 3 pages. Once the book and pages are added, I want to do some other things with the book and pages. Books and Pages are two separate reducers in my redux store and also two tables in my database. My current flow is this:

1. User creates new book.
2. ADD_BOOK_REQUEST action is called
3. ADD_PAGES_REQUEST action is called
4. Book is added to database which fires ADD_BOOK_SUCCESS
5. Pages are added to database which fires ADD_PAGES_SUCCESS

As mentioned above, after Steps 4 and 5 get executed, I'd like to do some other things with the book, but I'm not sure the best approach for this. Just to get it running for now, currently I have a setTimeout function that runs checking for the new book and 3 pages with that bookId. If book and 3 pages are in the store, do other things, if not, run the timeout again. I feel very certain this is not the best way to do this. :smile:

Comment: You should check out Redux Sagas. They make async flows easier to manage. It's a bit to wrap your head around. You can also just use redux-thunks with async/await.

Answer (score 8):

Gosha Arinich describes one possible solution in his post [Detecting state changes with Redux-Saga](https://goshakkk.name/detect-state-change-redux-saga/).

In that post, he suggests writing a `waitFor` function that would return when a provided selector finally returns `true`:

```
function* waitFor(selector) {
  if (yield select(selector)) return; // (1)

  while (true) {
    yield take('*'); // (1a)
    if (yield select(selector)) return; // (1b)
  }
}
```

It could be used like this:

```
function* someSaga() {
  yield call(waitFor, state => getCurrentUser(state) != null);
  // the user is logged in by now
}
```

Another possible solution would be a simpler custom middleware that does that checking after actions are dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1) In your React Component, you could connect to the piece of state that is updated by your reducer when ADD_PAGES_SUCCESS.  In `componentWillReceiveProps` you could check for that connected piece of state, and dispatch the action you want to be done after step (5) from within your Component.

...not great because `componentWillReceiveProps` can get hairy fast and should be avoided when possible.

2) Use redux-thunk or redux-saga:

With Redux-saga, in your ACTION handlers (sagas), you can `take` ACTIONS and do things like conditionally make API calls and `yield` (wait) for the server response, at which point you could trigger (`put`) more ACTIONs or make more API calls or do anything else you want.  This doesn't replace your reducers nor change your redux state.

Example:

```
// worker Saga: will be fired on ADD_PAGES_SUCCESS actions

function* doStuffAfterAddPages(action) {
  while (true) {
    yield take(ADD_PAGES_SUCCESS);

    try {
      let moreData;
      const result = yield call(api.doSomethingElse);

      if (result.isExpected) {
        moreData = yield call(api.doOtherStuff);
      } else {
        moreData = yield call(api.doOtherStuff);
      }

      yield put(OTHER_STUFF_COMPLETE, { data: moreData });
    } catch (error) {
      yield put(OTHER_STUFF_FAILED, { error: error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, this makes sense. I'm already using redux-thunk for updating the db so I think I'll stick with that. It occurs to me now that I could have an action that both the Books and Pages reducers react to. If the action creator is `addBookWithPages`, where does it live? I have actions/books.js and actions/pages.js does it live in one of these or is there a different place it should live? (I know redux doesn't really care but I'm trying to learn best practices if possible)

Comment: Actually, in thinking through this more, I'm still not sure how React knows to update the UI once OTHER_STUFF_COMPLETE is action is called. For example, let's say after book and pages are created I want to load the book in the UI. The only thing that comes to mind is to create a new piece of state that is something like `bookWithPagesReady` which has an ID. When `bookWithPagesReady` updates, my UI would see it and redirect the user and then clear that ID. This however seems cumbersome.

Comment: I would say that, with your setup, the action could live in books.js.  Or you could just combine those two files and call them 'books.js', since books contain pages.  And regarding bookWithPagesReady.. you could maybe do that.   Or you could look for the population of redux state's pages which you're likely connected to via redux with your Component. You can compare old props with new in componentWillReceiveProps.  If the new props has pages and the old one doesn't, well then it's time for that new action.